# Application Event Log Source: SideBySide, Event ID: 35 Lync.exe.Manifest error

Tags: windows-event-log, lync, skype, skype-for-business-2016

I'm seeing an error in my Windows event log with the following signature:

- **Log:** Application
- **Source:** SideBySide
- **EventId:** 35
- **Level:** Error
- **Description:** Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\lync.exe.Manifest".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\UccApi.DLL" on line 1. Component identity found in manifest does not match the identity of the component requested. Reference is UccApi,processorArchitecture="AMD64",type="win32",version="15.0.0.0". Definition is UccApi,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="15.0.0.0". Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I've not seen any negative symptoms related; but like to keep my logs clear of errors where possible.

How can I resolve this issue / prevent this error?

Comment: Just logging here for the benefit of others in future; already resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by amending the manifest file reported in the error (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\LYNC.EXE.MANIFEST`), changing the processor architecture of the UccApi DLL.

**Before:**

`<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="UccApi" version="15.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"></assemblyIdentity>`

**After:**

`<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="UccApi" version="15.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"></assemblyIdentity>`

Comment: These errors can usually be ignored, but nice job fixing it. Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - thank you for sharing the ACTUAL answer.  It's better than Microsoft's suggestion to just "ignore" the problem as suggested here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3077028/sidebyside-event-id-35-is-logged-in-the-application-log-when-you-start